# Suppose that for $a_n\geq b_n$ for all $n$. Show that $\varliminf_{n \to \infty} a_n\geq \varliminf_{n \to \infty} b_n$.

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

This is what I have so far:

Since $a_n\ge b_n$ for every $n$ then we have that $\inf\{a_n; n\ge k\} \ge \inf\{b_n; n\ge k\}$ for every $n$.  When we take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $$\varliminf_{n \to \infty} a_n\geq \varliminf_{n \to \infty} b_n$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Since the $\inf$s are increasing as a function of $k$, they have limits. Take the left hand side limit first, then the right hand side limit to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this solution is correct.